# where does the fable produced dll go?

Tags: fable-f#

I'm trying to decompile my build dll to see if `SuppressMessageAttribute` is kept.
This requires `CODE_ANALYSIS` to be a Defined Constant during build.

However searching the entire project folder, there are no `.dll` files.

I'm using the command
`dotnet fable start` to run fable with automatic recompilation when it changes
alone with
`npm run start`

for more context I'm following this article:
https://medium.com/@zaid.naom/f-interop-with-javascript-in-fable-the-complete-guide-ccc5b896a59f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fable doesn't create DLL files, and it cannot use DLL files.

Fable takes F# source code and compiles it directly to JavaScript.

It has to do this because DLL files are bytecode and JavaScript doesn't support bytecode.